Nu Html Checker in gitlab-ci pipeline
I want to integrate the Nu Html Checker (https://validator.github.io/validator/#docker-image) into a gitlab-ci pipeline (after live deployment). I want it to check the live-domain providing the URL. The result should be made available via artifacts. What image should I use?
I tried https://github.com/svenkreiss/html5validator but without success (html5validator: command not found).
Any help would be appreciated.

You can curl the web page you want to test again and save the html to a file via >>.
curl https://yxz.com/index.html >> page1.html

And then run the container with the page inside the container.
You can use any of the images that are provided:
For example: ghcr.io/validator/validator:17.11.1
